Conference call transcription using twilio
I am trying to transcribe the conference call from recording, as the conference is not directly supporting the transcription. Therefore, How I can achieve the transcription from the recording. What I have tried is:
<Dial>
    <Conference waitUrl="https://twimlets.com/holdmusic?Bucket=com.twilio.music.classical" startConferenceOnEnter="true" endConferenceOnExit="true" record="record-from-start" recordingStatusCallback="https://example.com/recording-callback.php" recordingStatusCallbackMethod="POST">CustomerConference</Conference>
</Dial>

it's working fine and returning the recordings also to the specified URL. Now I want to transcribe the recording.
$recordingUrl = $_REQUEST['RecordingUrl'];
$recordingSid = $_REQUEST['RecordingSid'];

$transcription = $twilio->transcriptions->create([
        "recordingSid" => $recordingSid,
        "callbackUrl" => "https://example.com/transcription-callback.php",
        "callbackMethod" => "POST"
    ]);

I am not getting any thing as a response on the transcription-callback.php Your guidance or help on transcribe conference call will be highly appreciated.
